# Stripe PaymentIntents with connected account + charge fee

Tags: php, laravel

my app will use stripe connected accounts to create a marketplace, I charge a 1€ fee for each payment my users receive when seeling their goods, I have experience with creating PaymentIntent for my customers but not with connected accounts, the docs are also a bit confusing.

Docs: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide

Now if we take a look at the docs, where paymentIntent is created. NO customer and NO payment method is supplied, ONLY stripe connected account id is supplied, how can I tell then what customer is getting charged.

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_CGGvfNiIPwLXiDwaOfZ3oX6Y');

$payment_intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'amount' => 1000,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'application_fee_amount' => 123,
  'transfer_data' => [
    'destination' => '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
  ],
]);
```

This is how I do charges for non-connected accounts for reference:

```
public function addPaymentCreateIntent(Request $request)
    {

        $stripeId = $request->input('stripeId');
        $paymentMethod = PaymentMethod::retrieve($request->input('paymentMethodId'));
        $paymentMethod->attach(['customer' => $stripeId]);
        
        $amount = (int) ($request->input('total')*100);
        
        $paymentIntent = PaymentIntent::create([
            'amount' => $amount,
            'payment_method' => $paymentMethod['id'],
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'currency' => 'eur',
            'customer' => $stripeId,
            //'setup_future_usage' => 'off_session',
            'metadata' => [
                'user_id' => $request->input('user_id'),
                'last4' => $paymentMethod['card']['last4'],
                'brand' => $paymentMethod['card']['brand'],
            ],
        ], 
        ['idempotency_key' =>  sha1(Carbon::now()) ]);


        return response()->json([
            'paymentIntent' => $paymentIntent,
        ], 200);  
    }
```

As you can see with no connected accounts customer and payment method is supplied, with connected accounts am I not needed to supply these??

Also why is it so hard to find an example of a connected account payment flow in the internet?

Comment: Edited OP to make my issue more clear

Answer (score 1):

I was working with exact same problem. Here is an example with node.js but I think the logic will be the same:

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount,
  currency,
  customer: customerId,
  metadata,
  description,
  application_fee_amount: 100,
  payment_method: paymentId,
},{
  stripeAccount: stripeAccountId,
});
```

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create?lang=php for more information you can look here at the customer, aplication_fee_amount and payment_method optional parameters